# How to make UICollection Scrolling Smoothy

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I created a collectionView. The cell is simple with only a UILabel on it. But the number of them is very much, for example, 33*50 +, in this case, view scrolls very laggy witch FPS 20 bellow.

I tried

1. change UILabel into CATextLayer

2.use CoreGraphics . Use drawRect to draw NSString

3.user YYText to draw async.

**All not work.**

Here is my demo [enter link description here](https://github.com/EpicKim/collectionview-demo).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve here ? . You are  using huge memory with section collectionview . why don't you use simple one cell and set 33 times 2 text to it

Comment: I want every cell act independently. Do you mean using TableView instead of UICollectionView?

Comment: Yes you can use UITableview

Comment: I don't think it'll work -_-

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filling your dataSource one time, you should add/fetch a small set each time user scrolls on UICollectionView.

Comment: How can i achieve that?

Comment: Please share your source code so that i can review.

Comment: I reviewed your project. if their is not restriction for items in row then decrease your variable value to 20 and then check the results.

let itemPerRow:Int = 20

Comment: i need to make it at less 33 perRow. Thank you any way.